# Issue with Pipfile.Lock while installing pillow with pipenv

Tags: python, django, docker, python-imaging-library

Trying to use pillow for images in Django.Using Pipenv to generate the virtual environment.Pillow is getting installed but Pipfile is not  able to lock properly.Below is the Pipfile.

```
name = "pypi"
url = "https://pypi.org/simple"
verify_ssl = true

[dev-packages]

[packages]
django = "==3.0.1"
psycopg2-binary = "==2.8.4"
django-crispy-forms = "==1.8.1"
django-allauth = "==0.41.0"

[requires]
python_version = "3.7"
```

Comment: what command you use for installation of the packages.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you use

```
pipenv install <package name>
```

while using `pipenv` for creating environment in python.

Answer (score 0):

Issue might happen because there might possibility that pip env path and your installed package path is differed. Make your package is been installed in same env as pipenv path